# IMAP attachment download - name is very strange

Tags: python, imap, email-attachments, imaplib

I am using the following code to download attachments from my outlook email:

```
for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")

for response in msg:
    if isinstance(response, tuple):
        # parse a bytes email into a message object
        msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
        # decode the email subject
        subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
        if isinstance(subject, bytes):
            # if it's a bytes, decode to str
            subject = subject.decode(encoding)
        # decode email sender
        From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
        if isinstance(From, bytes):
            From = From.decode(encoding)
        print("Subject:", subject)
        print("From:", From)
        # if the email message is multipart
        if msg.is_multipart():
            # iterate over email parts
            for part in msg.walk():
                # extract content type of email
                content_type = part.get_content_type()
                content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                try:
                    # get the email body
                    body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                except:
                    pass
                if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                    # print text/plain emails and skip attachments
                    print(body)
                elif "attachment" in content_disposition:
                    # download attachment
                    filename = part.get_filename()

                    if filename:
                        folder_name = clean("test_email_downloads")
                        if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                            os.mkdir(folder_name)
                        filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                        # download attachment and save it
                        fp= open(filepath, 'wb')
                        fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                        fp.close()
        else:
            # extract content type of email
            content_type = msg.get_content_type()
            # get the email body
            body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
            if content_type == "text/plain":
                # print only text email parts
                print(body)
        if content_type == "text/html":
            # if it's HTML, create a new HTML file and open it in browser
            folder_name = clean("test_email_downloads")
            if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                # make a folder for this email (named after the subject)
                os.mkdir(folder_name)
            filename = "index.html"
            filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
            # write the file
            open(filepath, "w").write(body)
            # open in the default browser
        print("="*100)
```

However, the files it saves aren't at all what they should be (I sent perfectly fine .xlsx files from another email).
They seem to be windows-1258 encoded for some reason, and I can't figure out why (or how to decode it, but this will come at a later stage).
Here is the output name of one of the attachments (the others are very similar):

=?windows-1258?Q?file_de=ECce=CCs_number_1.xlsx?=

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how I can decode it (also will my files always be encoded in windows-1258?)
The initial file name contains 'é' and 'è' as special characters, but it still doesn't quite explain the use of windows-1258 in my opinion...

Comment: Everything not 7-but ascii in a header must be encoded. This is a variant of Quoted Printable encoding (that’s what the Q means) and the chars et name is set by the sender.

Comment: don't suffer, https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools